# How to distinguish Full-time (FT) employment and Part-time (PT) employment when calculating employment rate?

Tags: macroeconomics, unemployment, natural-rate-unemployment

Which of the following is true for the Canadian labour force data for June, 2015, for unemployment, Full-time (FT) employment, and Part-time (PT) employment?

A)  Unemployment fell because FT employment rose more than PT employment fell

B)  Unemployment fell because PT employment rose more than FT employment fell

C)  Unemployment rose because FT employment rose less than PT employment fell

D)  Unemployment rose because PT employment rose less than FT employment fell

E)  Unemployment rose because FT employment and PT employment fell

The answer is A). This question indicates that PT and FT has mutual relationship. But I think we don't normally count PT when calculating unemployment rate. So how does the choice A) work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They must be counting full time/part time equivalents rather than individuals. They are basically comparing the hours worked versus the hours people report desiring to work. Thats the only explanation.